# Find the maximum and minimum of the restriction of $f$ to $K$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have the following problem.

> A sphere $K,$ has the equation: $x^2+y^2+(z+1)^2≤\frac{1}{4}$
>
> A function $f,$ is given by: $f(x,y,z)=-z \cdot e^{z-x^2-y^2+1}$
>
> It is known, that the point $(0,0,-1)$ is stationary. This point is the center of the sphere.
>
> Determine the global maximum and minimum of the restriction of $f$ to K, and indicate the coordinates of the points.

Okay, so I have come this far:

Rewriting the equation for the sphere to this: $-x^2-y^2=-\frac{1}{4}+(z+1)^2$

Inserting this in $f$ we get the following.

$$f=-z \cdot e^{z-\frac{1}{4}+(z+1)^2+1}$$

If I differentiate $f$ when it looks like this and solve the equation, $f'=0$, I get two solutions.

$$z=-\frac{1}{2}, z=-1$$

And since the point $(0,0,-1)$, these must be all the points where a maximum or minimum could be right?

However, I have talked to some of my peers about this problem, and they say that I also need to check the point where $z=-\frac{3}{2}$, cause that could also be a maximum/minimum.

I don't understand how they arrived at that, and I started to doubt my own answer. Can anyone clarify or help me about this. Do I also need to check for $z=-\frac{3}{2}$ and if so, why?

Comment: Are you sure that you've transcribed this correctly?  The point $(0,0,-1)$ is not on $K$ at all.

Comment: $(0,0-1)$ is the center of the sphere.

Comment: Yes, but it's not relevant to maximizing $f$ *on* the sphere.  Possibly you're meant to maximize $f$ in the ball where $x^2+y^2+(z+1)^2\leq\frac14$?  Then you would look for critical points in two places: wherever $f$ is stationary in the interior of the ball (giving only $(0,0,-1)$) and the critical points on the boundary sphere (which your question focusses on).

Comment: Shoot. It actually says in the problem that it is a closed sphere. I will edit the question.

Comment: A ball is a space of form $|x - x_0|^2 \leq r^2$; a sphere is of the form $|x - x_0|^2 = r^2$. Which do you mean here?

Comment: The problem says that it is a "closed sphere". So I am actually unsure of whether it is a ball of sphere. But let's say it's a ball, how would you go about this?

Comment: If they wrote an inequality with $ \leq $, then they probably wrote ‘sphere’ but meant the closed ball.  (This distinction between ‘sphere’ and ‘ball’ is a technicality that people don't always remember.)  If they only used the phrase ‘closed sphere’ and wrote an equation (or described the sphere some other way, say with centre and radius), then nothing indicates that they mean the ball.  But it's still suspicious any time somebody says ‘closed sphere’, since a sphere is always closed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting $ f ( x , y , z ) $ in terms of $ z $ alone is a good trick; that method doesn't always work well, but in this case, it works beautifully.  But you can't simply extremize $ g ( z ) = - z \, \mathrm e ^ { z − \frac 1 4 + ( z + 1 ) ^ 2 + 1 } $, because $ g $ is defined everywhere.  (Also, it's not good practice to use the same name $ f $, originally used for a function of three variables, for this function of one variable; they're not the same function, and they have different derivatives.)  Since the sphere only has solutions where $ x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 \geq 0 $, you also need to solve $ \frac 1 4 - ( z + 1 ) ^ 2 \geq 0 $ to get the possible values of $ z $.  So you are really extremizing $ g $ on the interval $ \big [ { - \frac 3 2 , - \frac 1 2 } \big ] $.  Thus, besides $ z = - 1 $ and $ z = - \frac 1 2 $ from $ g ' ( z ) = 0 $, you also get $ z = - \frac 3 2 $ and $ z = - \frac 1 2 $ from the boundary.  (Of course, you only have to check $ z = - \frac 1 2 $ once.)

This is to extremize $ f $ on the sphere; to extremize $ f $ on the closed ball, also check $ ( 0 , 0 , - 1 ) $, as you know.

Comment: Thank you! This really helps me a lot.

Comment: One more thing, how do I find the coordinates for the maximum and minimum?
I have found that for $z=-1$ we have a minimum, and for $z=-3/2$ we have a maximum. But what are the exact coordinates (x,y,z) for these points?

Comment: Or maybe it's not just one point, but actually a whole circular disc, the maximum and minimum lie?

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that I helped!

Once you have $z$, you solve the equation $-x^2-y^2=-\frac14+(z+1)^2$ to find $x$ and $y$.  And yes, when $z=-1$, you get a whole circle's worth of solutions.  (Not a disc, just a circle.  Just like a sphere is the boundary of a ball, so a circle is the boundary of a disc.)  Notice that every point on this circle gives the same value of $f(x,y,z)$, so the minimum is at all of them.